# Logging in a class with an injected logger

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, logging, dependency-injection, aspnetboilerplate

I am having issues with implementing logging in a class in the Web project in ASP.NET Boilerplate MVC project. Logging is working as expected in the controller in Web project and in Application project, but not in `RecordManager` class. It does not throw any error and it does not log anything in the `RecordManager` class.

```
public class MainController : Controller
{
    public Castle.Core.Logging.ILogger Logger { get; set; }

    public ActionResult Index(string SessionID)
    {
        Logger.Info("MainController - inside Index");
        var recordMgr = new RecordManager(SessionID);
        recordMgr.PushRecords();
    }
}

public class RecordManager
{
    public ILogger Logger { get; set; }
    private string _sessionID = string.Empty;

    public RecordManager(string sessionID)
    {
        _sessionID = sessionID;
        Logger = NullLogger.Instance;
        Logger.Info("RecordManager - inside constructor");
    }

    public void PushRecords()
    {
        Logger.Info("RecordManager - PushRecords - start");
    }
}
```

Tried to register `RecordManager` class manually, but I am getting a different error saying it does not satisfy the dependency for the string `sessionID`.

Comment: This is a strong point in favor of avoiding calling constructors as much as possible. See [this video](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2014/DEV-B412) for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use `Logger` in constructor, inject `RecordManager` and constructor-inject `ILogger`.

Pro: Clean.
Con: `SessionID` has public setter.

```
public class MainController : Controller
{
    public ILogger Logger { get; set; }
    public RecordManager _recordMgr { get; set; } // Add

    public ActionResult Index(string SessionID)
    {
        Logger.Info("MainController - inside Index");
        _recordMgr.SessionID = SessionID; // Modify
        _recordMgr.PushRecords(); // Modify
    }
}

public class RecordManager : ITransientDependency // Modify
{
    public ILogger Logger { get; set; }
    public string SessionID { get; set; } = string.Empty; // Modify

    public RecordManager(ILogger logger) // Modify
    {
        // _sessionID = sessionID; // Remove
        Logger = logger; // Modify
        Logger.Info("RecordManager - inside constructor");
    }

    public void PushRecords()
    {
        Logger.Info("RecordManager - PushRecords - start");
    }
}
```

Alternative: Inject `IIocResolver`, resolve `RecordManager` and constructor-inject `ILogger`.

Pro: Scope similar to `new`.
Con: Verbose.

```
public class MainController : Controller
{
    public ILogger Logger { get; set; }
    public IIocResolver IocResolver { get; set; } // Add

    public ActionResult Index(string SessionID)
    {
        Logger.Info("MainController - inside Index");
        using (var wrapper = IocResolver.ResolveAsDisposable<RecordManager>(new { sessionID = SessionID })) // Modify
        {
            var recordMgr = wrapper.Object; // Add
            recordMgr.PushRecords();
        }
    }
}

public class RecordManager : ITransientDependency // Modify
{
    public ILogger Logger { get; set; }
    private string _sessionID = string.Empty;

    public RecordManager(string sessionID, ILogger logger) // Modify
    {
        _sessionID = sessionID;
        Logger = logger; // Modify
        Logger.Info("RecordManager - inside constructor");
    }

    public void PushRecords()
    {
        Logger.Info("RecordManager - PushRecords - start");
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't necessarily have to inject an IoCResolver. You could just add the ILogger to the constructor parameters, and then pass the ILogger from the controller directly in. And you could keep the session ID as a parameter too.

Comment: Thanks @aaron. I understand the first approach and it worked, still could not get the second one.

Comment: Thanks @mason . I tred adding the ILogger to the constructor but in the logs output, I see that it is still referring to the maincontroller and not the record manager class.

Comment: @sridharRishab That's right - if your logger need to be specific to the class then you'll need to let DI resolve it rather than passing it yourself. I personally hate that style of logging though. I don't see any real need for the logger to know what class it's in.

Comment: @sridharRishab The second approach is closer to your original code — creating a new instance in the method and passing `SessionID` to the constructor.